# QWebElement information where on page it is rendered?

Tags: qt, dom, qtwebkit, qwebelement

Looks like access to DOM and rendering details of HTML tags are not availabel in qt 4.5.x .
Current snapshot  QWebElement looks like proper class to be used there
Anybody can give me info if is it possible to get from  QWebElement information where on page it was rendered ?
Or there are other ways to get that information ?
TIA, regards

Answer (score 3):

In Qt 4.5, you need to write that as a [JavaScript expression](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html) and evaluate that with [QWebFrame::evaluateJaveScript()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference's sake: for 4.6 and up, [QWebElement.geometry()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwebelement.html#geometry) is the best way to do this.  Otherwise, user134841's answer about calling into JavaScript is really the only alternative.